# Items in Wordpress widget forms are being hidden whenever they are initially are added, what could be causing this issue?

Tags: wordpress, widget

Whenever I add a widget under Appearance -> Widgets, all of the items in the form load, and then disappear after a second or two. This is happening for all widgets, and this is what they look like when it happens:

[image]

Something is changing all type tags to hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" ...>
```

And all of the tags containing text get "display: none" added to them:

```
 <div class="widget-description" style="display: none;">
    A calendar of your site’s Posts.
</div>
```

The widget description class also gets display:none added to them.

However, when I reload the page after adding the widget, the form loads as expected. It only happens when the widget is first added. Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended after updating Wordpress to 5.2.2 and above